# How to run azure power shell by ansible playbook?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ansible, azure-functions, azure-powershell

Now i want to run some power shell scipts like New-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName 'Testing' -Name 'Runbook02' -ResourceGroupName 'rg' -Type Python3
How to do it by ansible-playbook ?

Comment: You can use https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_powershell_module.html

Comment: Hello, If the answer was helpful, Please  [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Comment: I checked your question as well as the answer and found that it is indeed an effective method. Please follow his steps and methods to try it first. If you have any questions and need help, we are happy to answer them.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve the above requirement by following this [**`Blog here`**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_powershell_module.html) to configure in our local.

The same command we can run with PowerShell as well to create runbook for our Automation Accounts.

***Screenshot for reference:-***

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer this ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-*** [***Using Ansible with Azure***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/overview)